# Printing an array of tokens one per line

Tags: python, token

After tokenizing a file and left with an array of tokens... how would you go about printing each token one per line in python

Comment: I'd go printing one token per line... What is your question?

Comment: Much more information, please.

Answer (score 2):

```
for token in tokens:
    print token
```